# complex ternary operator with logical operator

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i am debugging a really small java script plugin which i have seemed to figured out most parts of but i am having certain difficulties understanding the below function :

```
CBPFWTabs.prototype._show = function( idx ) {
        if( this.current >= 0 ) {
            this.tabs[ this.current ].className = '';
            this.items[ this.current ].className = '';
        }
        // change current
        this.current = idx != undefined ? idx : this.options.start >= 0 && this.options.start < this.items.length ? this.options.start : 0;
        this.tabs[ this.current ].className = 'tab-current';
        this.items[ this.current ].className = 'content-current';
    };
```

i started running through each piece of the function and putting the pieces together . and eventually i was quite successful , MDN's great documentation helped too , however , i am still having difficulty understanding the below line :

```
this.current = idx != undefined ? idx : this.options.start >= 0 && this.options.start < this.items.length ? this.options.start : 0;
```

The combination of ternary operators and logical operators really seems confusing , to simplify the above i tried reading it in plain english , and my best interpretation was :

if idx is **not equal** to undefined and idx is **equal** to this.current ... and  i am pretty much stuck at this , what happens next i can't even guess .  if somebody could just interpret that line in plain englsih , it would be great ! .

**EDIT ::** : i just read a really nice article link posted below in the comments , so just wanted to clarify , given the below line on code (a nested ternary operator) :

```
int i = 5;
string result = i % 2 == 0 ? "a" : i % 3 == 0 ? "b" : i % 5 == 0 ? "c" : i % 7 == 0 ? "d" : "e";
```

the `e` in the end is functioning more like the default case in a switch case , am i right ? . 
Thank you .

Alexander .

Comment: There is a [post](http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post5273_how-to-read-nested-ternary-operators) about how to read and format nested ternaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've posted is two (nested) ternary operators:

```
this.current = idx != undefined ? idx : c;
```

... where `c` is the result of:

```
 (this.options.start >= 0 && this.options.start < this.items.length ? this.options.start : 0);
```

In other words, the nested ternary operator is evaluated as the `false` path of the 1st ternary operator.

---

If that still isn't clear; think of it like this;

```
if (idx != undefined) {
    this.current = idx;
} else if (this.options.start >= 0 && this.options.start <  this.items.length) {
    this.current = this.options.start;
} else {
    this.current = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i just added an additional question .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik: Glad it helped. The answer to your additional question is "yes", but I wouldn't recommend using ternary operators which  are so complicated... its much easier, and less confusing, to break it out into `if/ else` statements.

Comment: unfortunately , contemporary java script revolves around such syntax . nvm , TY  .

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator `a = cond ? b : c` can be interpreted as follows:

```
if (cond) {
    a = b;
} else {
    a = c;
}
```

As you can see, there is a nested ternary operator in the "c" part, so you can just put another nested if in there to help you translate it to english.
Hope that makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could write this line using if else like this :

```
if(idx != undefined) {this.current = idx
} else if (this.options.start >= 0 && this.options.start < this.items.length) {this.current = this.options.start
} else {this.current = 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Break it down into parts:

`this.current = idk != undefined ? idk : ...`
`this.current` is equal to `idx` if `idx` is not `undefined`.

`this.current = ... ? ... : this.options.start >= 0 && this.options.start < this.items.length ? this.options.start : ...`
Otherwise it'll be equal to `this.options.start` if `this.options.start` is greater than or equal to 0, but lower than `this.items.length`.

`this.current = ... ? ... : ... && ... ? ... : 0`
Otherwise it'll be equal to 0.

Try to avoid complex ternary operators like that, a simple `if` is much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using plain if / else

```
if (idx != undefined) {
    this.current = idx;    
} else if (this.options.start >= 0 && this.options.start < this.items.length) {
    this.current = this.options.start
} else {
    this.current = 0;
}
```

It may help to think about it as if/then/else for assignment operations. Although you can use it for many other things, it isn't typically recommended for complex if/else program flow. Because it is difficult to follow it along several lines of code. A good example of when you should feel comfortable using it would be like so..

```
var foo = amount > 5 ? 'greater than 5' : 'less than or equal to 5';
// amount === 7 --> foo is now set to 'greater than 5'
// amount === 4 --> foo is now set to 'less than or equal to 5'
```

Just an example to show an acceptable level of complexity, nest 2 should be fine as well but i would avoid nesting much more than that, even 2 can slow down the guy reading your code.